# リスト内の要素を照合し、抽出したい（改訂版）

Tags: python

[一つ前の質問](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/61234/19110)の前提に変更点があったので新しく質問させて頂きます。
前回のリストAの0番目に要素を追加しました。

```
A = [
  [1,'c', 0, 1, 0, 0],
  [0,'d', 1, 1, 0, 1],
  [0,'a', 0, 0, 0, 0],
  [0,'b', 1, 0, 0, 0],
  [0,'c', 0, 1, 0, 0],
  [0,'a', 0, 0, 0, 1],
  [0,'b', 1, 0, 0, 0],
  [0,'d', 1, 0, 0, 1],
]
```

以下がAというリストに対して行いたい処理です。
「1番目（アルファベット）は同じだが、0番目または2~5番目（数字）が一致しなければリスト化して抽出する」

最終的に下のようなリストを作りたいです。

```
result = [
 [0,'a', 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0,'a', 0, 0, 0, 1],
 [0,'c', 0, 1, 0, 0],
 [1,'c', 0, 1, 0, 0],
 [0,'d', 1, 1, 0, 1],
 [0,'d', 1, 0, 0, 1],
]
```

前の質問でkunifさんから頂いた回答である、以下のプログラムは理解しました。
これにリストAの0番目の要素も2-5番目の要素も両方参照するという指示を加えるには、どのような変更をしたら良いのでしょうか。

```
A = list(map(list, set(map(tuple, A)))) # 先に重複除去
A.sort()

result = []
work = []
prev = A[0]       # あらかじめ1つ取得・格納
work.append(prev) #

for i in range(1,len(A)): # 2つ目から始める
    row = A[i]
    if prev[0] != row[0]:       # 先頭データが変わった時
        if len(work) > 1:       # 2つ以上のデータがある時
            result.extend(work) # 結果に追加

        work = []               # 作業用配列クリア

    prev = row                  # 直前データ更新
    work.append(row)            # 作業用配列に追加

if len(work) > 1:       # 2つ以上の未処理データがある時
    result.extend(work) # 結果に追加
```

ご教授お願い致します。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

こちらを参考に、ソートのキーを各行の2つ目のデータに指定します。
[python sorted のkeyってなんぞ](https://qiita.com/inon3135/items/70b1ed6706579bd48edf)
[ソート HOW TO](https://docs.python.org/ja/3/howto/sorting.html)

変更した部分にコメントを入れています。

```
A = list(map(list, set(map(tuple, A))))
A.sort(key=lambda x:x[1]) # ソートのキーを各行の2つ目のデータに指定

result = []
work = []
prev = A[0]
work.append(prev)

for i in range(1,len(A)):
    row = A[i]
    if prev[1] != row[1]: # 各行の2つ目のデータが変わった時
        if len(work) > 1:
            result.extend(work)

        work = []
        prev = row        # 直前データ更新はこの位置の方が良さそう

    work.append(row)

if len(work) > 1:
    result.extend(work)
```

---

**追記**
上記で`work`リストは、2つ目('a'/'b'/'c'等)の要素が同じである行をいったん貯めておいて、最終的に2行以上あるかチェックして`result`リストに入れるかどうかの判断のための作業用です。
`prev`はリストといっても常に1個しか入っていませんが、上記「2つ目('a'/'b'/'c'等)の要素が同じである行」かどうかのチェック用に直前データとして格納しておくためのものです。

Comment: 期待していた結果になりました。ところで、workとprevというリストはどんな役割を果たしているのでしょうか。理解不足でお手数をおかけします。